# JCarousel não ativa o botão Next

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um carousel que é criado dinamicamente com dados vindos do banco de dados. Só que ao criar dinamicamente parece que ele não ativa o Next. Como posso resolver isso?
Seguem os códigos:

[image: HTML DA PÁGINA]

JQUERY:

```
$('.jcarousel-imagem-produto')
    .jcarousel({
      vertical: true
    });

    $('.jcarousel-control-prev-imagem-produto')
    .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('inactive');
    })
    .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
      $(this).addClass('inactive');
    })
    .jcarouselControl({
      target: '-=1'
    });


    $('.jcarousel-control-next-imagem-produto')
    .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('inactive');
    })
    .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
      $(this).addClass('inactive');
    })
    .jcarouselControl({
      target: '+=1'
    });
```

AQUI É ONDE FAÇO COM QUE A IMAGEM APAREÇA:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode criar o controle de avançar e voltar na mão.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de como eu poderia fazer isso? Mas ali em cima ele já não cria o controle? O problema que eu me referi que ele funciona se eu colocar as LI sem ser criadas dinamicamente. Se eu criá-las dinamicamente simplesmente ele não aciona ou não entende as L'is